# Copy paste in CTreeView labels

Tags: c++, mfc, treeview, copy-paste

I have a control derived from `CTreeView` in MFC SDI application (containing splitter, `CTreeView` and `CDetailsView` basically). What is working for me is editing labels in nodes of tree view by processing the end of edit

```
ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(TVN_ENDLABELEDIT, &CNavigationView::OnTvnEndlabeledit)
```

I want to add copy/paste functionality with `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V`. I think this deals with `TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT` and `TVN_KEYDOWN` but I can't figure out how to make this work correctly, may be some ideas or sample?

```
void CNavigationView::OnTvnEndlabeledit(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMTVDISPINFO pTVDispInfo = reinterpret_cast<LPNMTVDISPINFO>(pNMHDR);
    if (pTVDispInfo && pTVDispInfo->item.pszText)
    {
    }
}
```

When I am trying to paste text from Notepad, `pTVDispInfo->item.pszText` is `NULL` according to debugger.

I am working in Visual Studio 2013, Windows 8.

Comment: What do you mean by 'add copy/paste functionality'? Adding multiple items in one go, when someone presses ctrl-p with the focus on your control? If it's just handling editing an item through copy/paste, that should work without any special code for it (i.e., when someone starts editing an item, and presses ctrl-v, the content of the clipboard will be pasted into the edit control that shows when the editing starts).

Comment: @Roel No, I mean for example copy string from notepad for example and paste it into label which is being edited in treeview. And backwards, copy content of label in treeview item and paste into notepad (any other app)

Comment: Then I'm not sure what the problem is - handling copy/paste is the same as handling other edits. In its most rudimentary form, you do tree.SetItemText(pTVDispInfo->item.hItem, pTVDispInfo->item.pszText); from within TVN_ENDLABELEDIT . Nothing special about copy/paste - this is handled by the edit control.

Comment: Problem is that pTVDispInfo->item.pszText is NULL when I am pasting text from another application

Comment: Does the text on the label change when you paste? Because the content of item.pszText is what you see before the 'end edit'. Have you tried this pasting from notepad? Maybe the other application doesn't put in CF_TEXT format content into the clipboard. Just speculating here, I tried a new test application with only a tree control (Win8.1, VS2013) and It Works For Me (TM).

Comment: Yes, I am pasting from notepad and this doesn't work. Text is not changing, I have updated the question with more info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84365/discussion-between-demonplus-and-roel).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you already have an accelerator defined in you application that also uses Ctrl-V. So inside the inplace edit control you press Ctrl+V but this causes a WM_COMMAND message to be generated from the accelerator. The accelerator executes something that aborts the inplace edit job.

In such a case You need a PreTranslateMessage handler that checks if keyboard input arrives with Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V and directs this input to the edit control that is open instead of letting the frame window accelerator to handle it.

Just set a breakpoint and look into the callstack and check what is executed when the inplace edit stops.